# How to get current position in NSArray in objective-C

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsarray

New to iOS coding, so this is probably more of a syntax question than anything else. I am trying to implement a UIImageView loaded with an array of image objects. On right swipe, I want to move to the next object in the array, and load it into the view. I have the array loaded fine, just don't know how, syntactically, how to get the current position in the array. I realize this is a total n00b question, so free reputation cred for you.

Heres some code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"], nil];
    imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];

}

- (IBAction)swipeRightGesture:(id)sender {
 imageView.image = [imageArray somethingsomething];//load next object in array
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)swipeRightGesture:(id)sender 
{
     NSUInteger index = [imageArray indexOfObject:imageView.image] + 1;

     // do something here to make sure it's not out of bounds
     //

     imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:index];//load next object in array
}
```

Comment: note that as indexOfObject: returns the lowest index whose corresponding array image is equal to imageView.image, this solution requires that all images in the array are unique.

Comment: I just assumed that all images are unique, otherwise, why have two pointers of same object stored in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays don't have a current position. They're not stream like, they're just containers.

So there's two ways to fix this:

1. Keep your array position separately, as an `NSInteger` in your view controller instance. Increment and decrement it as needed. Use `objectAtIndex` to get the object there.
2. Find the position of your current image using `indexOfObject`. Increment and decrement that as needed. Use `objectAtIndex` to get the object there.

I'd recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is given below .

```
-(void)next
{
    if (currentIndex < (count - 1))
    {
        currentIndex ++;
        NSLog(@"current index : %d", currentIndex);
    }
}

-(void) previous
{
    if (currentIndex > 1) {
        currentIndex --;
        [self.commsLayer  performOperation:currentIndex];
        NSLog(@"current index : %d", currentIndex);
    }else
    {
        if (currentIndex == 1) {
            currentIndex --;
            NSLog(@"first current index : %d", currentIndex);
        }
    }
}
```